# Where is Ce'Nedra's tree?

Tags: the-belgariad, david-eddings

In The Belgariad  Ce'Nedra is half Dryad, the daughter of Ran Borune XXIII, Emperor of Tolnedra, and the Dryad Ce'Vanne.  As I understand it all Dryads are supposed to have a tree, and they're are not to go too far from it.  Ce'Nedra travels quite a bit making me wonder if she has a tree at all?

There is however mention of her tree in Castle of Wizardry, when she gets the present of two acorns (I think) she explains to Garion that they are gifts from the trees, one them from "her" tree.

So where is her Tree, and how come she doesn't need to be near it all the time?

Answer (score 3):

That she doesn't need to be near it all the time is easily hand-waved away by the fact that she's **half** dryad.

Although that raises the question of how her mother Ce'Vanne, a full dryad, was presumably able to live in Tol Honeth while she was alive and married to Ran Borune Nth. Maybe they had her tree moved?

Comment: As I recall, Tol Honeth is actually pretty close to the Dryads' forest.

Comment: She gets a tree in the Mallorean, book one, I think (Garion does too), as it's the only way for her to have children.

Comment: No, the fruit of the tree was grown from her tree. See Castle of Wizardry, where the tree was planted.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't explicitly stated. The best clue is that Xera retrieved two acorns, one from Ce'Nedra's tree, and the second from Queen Xantha's tree. Presumably they were in the same location, which I would assume is the Dryad Forest. It's exact location is never specified.